# Is there anyway we can write bootable DMG or ISO file on a hard disk partition?

Tags: macos

I am trying to install Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) on my Acer Aspire 5733 laptop. But for some reason I am not able to install and it throws kernel panic such as:

> unable to find driver for this platform: \"ACPI\".n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.2/iokit/Kernel
>   /IOPlatformExpert.cpp:1378

I believe it It is something to do with USB driver issue so I wanna boot the DMG from hard disk and give it a try.

My question is nothing to do with installing Mac OS X on an Intel PC but if there is any suggestion that would enable the possibility of writing ISO/DMG bootable file on a hard disk partition.

I know we can use transmac but that will allow only to write on usb.

Comment: how about **toast**?http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40585/how-to-make-a-bootable-disk-from-an-image-with-toast

Comment: It is a windows laptop. Toast is mac app

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem with "bootability" with Macs.  Macs do not require a boot sector or anything special from a disc for it to be bootable the way a PC does.  A Mac's firmware can locate and boot OS X from any media it can see regardless of whether or not it has been 'blessed'.  As such, there is no difference between a Mac 'bootable' ISO and any other ISO.

The only issue you face is how to make a PC attempt to actually boot from it.  That part I couldn't tell you because I've never had a need to hack it.  But I can tell you that, on a real Mac, all you'd need to do is extract the contents of the DMG/ISO to a hard drive partition.  That's it.  So if you can clear that hurdle, the rest is a hackintosh-specific issue.